# Псевдо прямая трансляция на PHP

Tags: php

У меня есть видео(mp4), я хочу делать вид, что это прямая трансляция. Соответственно у меня на странице есть тег `<video>`(HTML5), я хочу разместить в `src` ссылку на свой код PHP, который бы отдавал только определенную часть видео, то есть например если я хочу чтобы трансляция закончилась в 20:00, полный видос нельзя было посмотреть в 19:58, а соответственно только некоторую часть(без 2-х минут). Испытываю проблемы с написанием этого кода, подскажите куда копать?

P.S возможно если на PHP такое нельзя сделать, рассмотрю другие веб языки

Comment: Мне кажется, будет проще запустить псевдотрансляцию через ffmpeg (с выводом в hls или dash), чем пытаться городить что-то своё

Comment: Боюсь Вам это будет сложно реализовать. Дело в том, что как только клиент получил страницу и с нее запросил `video` - ему пошел прямой поток который будет отдавать Ващ `php`-скрипт и далее Вы никак управлять этим не можете т.к отдаете сразу весь `video`-файл. Для анализа же текущего времени и принятия решения отдавать контент или нет Вам нужно, чтобы клиент периодически запрашивал у Вас данные,а это возможно, если Вы будете отдавать ему данные кусками - например разбивать видео файл на мелкие по несколько минут и запрашивать их по-очереди - а это протокол `rtsp` - почитайте.

Comment: @phpBear да, я хотел разбивать видео на части по 5 секунд и отдавать их, а там с помощью js склеивать, чтобы не было рывков, дело в том, что это костыль, но насколько сильный и вывезет ли так обычный хостинг, например 100 пользователей в full hd

Comment: @andreymal ок, слышал, но думал что это дольше, сейчас погуглю

Comment: @andreymal а можно, подробнее, гуглится совсем разная информация, раку в этом, сложно разобраться

Comment: Как я понимаю на хостинге нельзя работать с `ffmpeg` нужно брать VPS?