# Red5 vs FFmpeg что выбрать?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, red5

У меня есть VPS, и я хочу видео хранящееся на нём транслировать, а потом выводить на сторонний сайт, желательно используя `<video>`(html 5). Подскажите что мне лучше использовать Red5 vs FFmpeg и как их использовать? А также как мне обойти использование Flash Player?

P.S хочу управлять этим с PHP, но если Java или Python с этим лучше справится, буду не против)

Comment: Хранящиеся видео — это просто файлы. Трансляция видео — это просто скачивание файла с сервера. Никакие Red5, FFmpeg и Flash совершенно не требуются для скачивания файла. Если вы корректно описали свою задачу, вам не нужно использовать ничего из этого.

Comment: Но если вы хотите [псевдо прямую трансляцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1363860), то ffmpeg с флагом `-re` и выводом в какой-нибудь `-f hls playlist.m3u8` сможет генерировать на лету файлы для как бы живой трансляции

Comment: @andreymal хорошо, спасибо

Comment: @andreymal а потом, я смогу просто в `<video>` `src="IPserver/playlist.m3u8"`? или что это означает?

Comment: А это уже почитайте где-нибудь что такое HLS и как его воспроизводить в браузере

Comment: @andreymal ок, спасибо

Comment: @andreymal `сможет генерировать на лету файлы для как бы живой трансляции`. То есть это должно работать так: из видео ряда генерируются оптимизированный файл в этом плейлисте, а потом уже они транслируются? Если это не так, можете объяснить в кратце, как это должно быть)